# Avoiding unchecked casts of nested Maps in Java

Tags: java, generics, nested-generics

I have a Java data structure which results from deserialising this JSON:

```
{
  'level1 value1': {
    'level2 value1': {
      'level3 value1': [ "25", "45", "78" ],
      // ...
      'level3 valueN': [ "59", "17", "42" ]
    },
    // ...
    'level2 valueN': {
      'level3 value1': [ "34", "89", "54" ],
      // ...
      'level3 valueN': [ "45", "23", "23" ]
    },
  },
  // ...
  'level1 valueN': {
    // ...
  }
}
```

In Java, this becomes:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>> data;
```

Of course, the number of levels is arbitrary, so I can't really nest collections in the variable declaration. What I'm doing instead is this:

```
void traverse(Map<String, ?> children) {
  for (Map.Entry<String, ?> node : data.entrySet()) {
    if (node.getValue() instanceof Map) {
      doSomethingWithNonLeafNode((Map<String, Map<String, ?>>) node);
    } else if (node.getValue() instanceof List) {
      doSomethingWithLeafNode((Map <String, List<String>>) node);
    }
  }
}


void doSomethingWithNonLeafNode(Map <String, Map<String ?>> node) {
  // do stuff
}


void doSomethingWithLeafNode(Map <String, List<String>> node) {
  // do stuff
}
```

This obviously a) uses some unchecked casts, and b) is ugly. I tried to define new types to get around this:

```
private interface Node extends Map<String, Map<String, ?>> {
}

private interface LeafNode extends Map<String, List<String>> {
}

// ...

    if (node.getValue() instanceof Map) {
      doSomethingWithNonLeafNode((Node) node);
    } else if (node.getValue() instanceof List) {
      doSomethingWithLeafNode((LeafNode) node);
    }
```

However, this gives me a runtime exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.foo.ReportDataProcessor$Node
```

How can I do this in a clean, warning-free fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining new types doesn't help you because the JSON deserializer doesn't know about your Node & LeafNode interfaces, thus the concrete collection objects produced can't implement them.

Since you don't actually know the element types of your maps in advance, there is no compile time type safety to be enforced: you can only rely on runtime type checks. Therefore generics just complicates your life and makes your code uglier, but doesn't bring you any benefit.

So I think the least worst solution here would be to drop generics, using nongeneric `Map` and `List` types in your code.

Comment: Yeah, I think "least worst" will have to win here. Java's not really the best language for this sort of thing, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this nicely without a union type.

If you think about it, the `Map` you're dealing with can actually contain two types of objects - either another map for the level below, or a list of strings for the leaf node.  Therefore the generic parameter for this map will have to be some common supertype of both maps and lists.  And ultimately, when you detect that you have a leaf node and are dealing with a list, you'll *have* to cast.

Answer (score 1):

For a cleaner solution, you may forget about Map as the the container and create an object to represent the tree, better

```
public class Node{
   String text;
   List<String> data;
   List<Node> children; 
}
```

And you can implement the current way of populating the tree using Map into using this tree structure. If the Node's children are not empty then you don't have to think about the data.

```
void traverse(Node node) {
  if(node.getChildren()!=null){
      doSomethingWithNonLeafNode(node);
      // Or for recursion if you need
      // List<Node> children=node.getChildren();
      // for(Node c:children){
      //    traverse(c);
      // }
  }else{
      doSomethingWithLeafNode(node);
  }
}
```

Comment: `extends HashMap<String, Map<String, ?>>` would not make any difference: there would still be a class cast exception.

Comment: @PéterTörök Yep, I took it the other way round :) He can cast the Node object to HashMap but not HashMap to Node.